# re.findall string. Slight modifications to the string in the same command?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using Python 3.6. I am currently searching for a string in a read.txt file. However, is there a way to produce slight modifications to that string? I give you an example with the code I have:

```
lines = [] # create an empty list
str1 = "does not include a report on internal controls"
with open(read.txt, 'r') as f:
  line2 = f.read()
  var1 = re.findall(str1, line2, re.I) # find str1 or str2 in read.txt
  if len(var1) > 0:
     lines.append('1') # if it exists, append a 1 to the list "lines"
  else:
     lines.append('0') # otherwise a 0
```

My question is, can I easily change a preposition in my str1? I would also like to search for "does not include a report ***of*** internal controls" ("of" instead of "on"). May be splitting the string into two and allowing for "on/of" within the re.findall command line? Don't know how to do it... Any suggestion?

Thank you so much for your time!
Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternation:

```
str1 = r"does not include a report (on|of) internal controls"
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/Z5qTl4/1

---

As @WiktorStribiżew  suggests (see comments), in this case, you could replace the alternation `(on|of)` with `o[nf]`.

Comment: It is not advisable to have alternative branches that match at the same location. `(on|of)` is better replaced with `o[nf]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sounds like a better proposal. Could you pls help with a link explaining why such alternations should be avoided. Or maybe it's just that the branching is less performant?

Comment: In the situation with two or three short fixed width alternatives the difference is negligible. I do not say this should be avoided as it might be more readable, however such cases might involve redundant backtracking in case more alternatives with quantified sub patterns are added.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh cool, makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298227/python-regex-hang-on-long-string), this is a clear example when using two alternatives that can match at the same location can cause huge trouble.

Comment: Thank you guys, that is what I was looking for. Nice add-ons to the main issue.